# No puedo insertar datos con AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Tengo una aplicación web que estoy realizando, pero a la hora de insertar los datos no se guardan. No sé qué pasa, ya revise el código y todo esta bien con otro que había hecho antes.

Acá obtengo los valores de los *input*

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(){

    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
   
   
    

    Insertar(input1,input2);
    


});




  function Insertar(nombre,edad){

    console.log(nombre);
    console.log(edad);


    //Instancia del objecto
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //TIPO DE PETICION Y LA RUTA DISTINATARIA DONDE LLEGA EL DATO
    xml.open("POST","../Model/Registro.php",true);


    //TIPO DE CONTENIDO A ENVIAR
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 


    //CONTROLO LA RESPUESTA HTTP
    xml.onreadystatechange = function (){

        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){

            Mostrar();

        }
    }

    xml.send("nombre="+nombre+"?edad="+edad);




}
```

Lo gracioso es que el método mostrar se ejecuta, pero no sé porqué no se envían los datos a la base; el método no lo mostraré porque no es necesario, porque funciona.

Acá envío los datos que obtengo por medio de *AJAX*

```
<?php

include "Gestor_datos.php";


if(isset($_POST["nombre"])  && isset($_POST["edad"])){

    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $edad = $_POST["edad"];
 
    $enviar = new gestorData();
    $enviar->Insertar($nombre,$edad);

    
    
   

}


?>
```

Acá inserto los datos

```
<?php

include_once "Base_datos.php";



class gestorData extends Base_datos{




  
    public function Insertar($nombre,$edad){

        $sql= $this->Conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (Nombre,Edad) VALUES (:nom,:ed)");
        $valor=$sql->execute([":nom"=>$nombre,":ed"=>$edad]);
        echo "Datos insertados";


    }



    public function Mostrar(){


        return $sql = $this->Conectar()->query("SELECT COUNT(*)  as total FROM usuarios");


    }


}


?>
```

Todas las rutas de las carpetas están correctas, ya las revisé, pero no sé porqué no se guardan los datos

Comment: Probablemente solo falta codificar los valores para incluirlos en la petición: [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent). Aunque te sugiero cambiar de `XMLHttpRequest` a [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) que me parece más manejable.

Comment: La aplicación me la pidieron con Ajax por mi ps usaría también Fetch pero so ellos los que manda así toca con AJAX.

Comment: _AJAX_ es un acrónimo para _Asynchronous JavaScript And XML_ y se puede aplicar con diferentes métodos, como _XMLHttpRequest_,  _fetch_ y otros proporcionados por librerías. Por ahora, prueba con `xml.send("nombre="+encodeURIComponent(nombre)+"&edad="+encondeURIComponent(edad));` y, toma nota, se deben separar los campos con `& en lugar de `?`

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias tu ayuda me sirvió era cambiar el ? por el & que tonto jejeje no me acordaba dure horas viendo por que no funcionada y nunca pensé que fuera eso de nuevo                                                                                                        muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Era cambiar el signo ? por el & al enviar los datos por send()

Comment: No es recomendable una respuesta de este tipo, porque la pregunta seguramente será cerrada porque el problema es por un error tipográfico.